# Django/South Model Field Cascade Update

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-orm, django-south

Let's say **I have two models in two apps**:

```
"Products" app
ProductCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    associated_code = models.OneToOneField('self', blank=True, null=True)

"Accounts" app
InventoryItem(models.Model):
    productCode = models.ForeignKey(ProductCode)
```

Now **I need to update the 'max_length' of ProductCode.code to 20**, so I create a south migration (Django 1.5, Postgres) like so:

```
manage.py schemamigration --auto products
```

...and it creates a migration for me that reads:

```
def forwards(self, orm):  
    db.alter_column(u'products_productcode', 'code', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=20, primary_key=True))
```

Then I run the migration.
EDIT: then I run `schemamigration` *again*, and another migration is created for  `associated_code`. Then I run `migrate` again and `associated_code` is now `character varying(20)` in my db.

**But when I look at my db I see**:

```
accounts_inventoryitem:
  product_code_id | character varying(10) | not null

products_productcode:
  code            | character varying(20) | not null
  associated_code | character varying(20) |
```

**It looks like South is not cascading my field update across relationships.**
This results in errors when I try to load data:

```
Could not load products.ProductCode(pk=abcdefghijklmno): value too long for type character varying(10)
```

**Is this due to the circular model relationship of `ProductCode`?

Or maybe because my model has has an FK relationship across apps?** (it also has a M2M relationship in another app not shown above)
**Or possibly because `code` is the PK to my model?**